# Postgres full text search DQL user defined function problems

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, full-text-search

```
/**
 * PGSearchFunction ::= "PG_SEARCH" "(" StateFieldPathExpression "," StringPrimary ")"
 */
class PGSearch extends FunctionNode
{
    public $searchColumn = null;
    public $search = null;

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->searchColumn = $parser->StateFieldPathExpression();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->search = $parser->StringPrimary(); 
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return sprintf("%s @@ to_tsquery('english', %s)", $this->searchColumn->dispatch($sqlWalker), $this->search->dispatch($sqlWalker));

    }

}
```

[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string. Any suggestions on how to prevent doctrine from look at this like a standard SQL expression? Using doctrine 2.2 btw.

Comment: What are you passing into the `PG_SEARCH` function in your DQL?

Comment: $em->createQuery("SELECT i FROM MyBundle:Invoice i WHERE PG_SEARCH(i.search, 'virus')");

Comment: Can you try `$em->createQuery("SELECT i FROM MyBundle:Invoice i WHERE PG_SEARCH(i.search, 'virus') = true");`

Comment: That worked, was hoping for a cleaner solution, but that will do. Thank you good sir.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately Doctrine's support for functions like this appears to be non-existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do `$em->createQuery("SELECT i FROM MyBundle:Invoice i WHERE PG_SEARCH(i.search, 'virus') = true");`